# Check all column name in the tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Good day!

The database has a table that you want to archive. A copy of the table, with the addition of the prefix name "ARCH_".

e.g. Table: BALANCE. Archiving table: ARCH_BALANCE.

I need to write a query to check: that in the tables "ARCH_%" present all fields of the base tables. *also have a database table that are not archived.

I wrote the following query:

```
    select distinct COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS res
where TABLE_NAME in(
  SELECT TABLE_NAME  
  FROM all_tables core_t
  where TABLE_NAME not like 'ARCH_%' AND
  EXISTS (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM all_tables hist_t
    WHERE hist_t.TABLE_NAME  = concat('ARCH_', core_t.TABLE_NAME)

  )
) and COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (
  select COLUMN_NAME 
  from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
  where TABLE_NAME  = concat('ARCH_', res.TABLE_NAME)
);
```

Parts of the code works, but generally runs indefinitely.

Perhaps there is somebody other ideas.

Comment: Please fix your tags: is it MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: I think it's neither, looks like Oracle...

Comment: Did you analysed plan of the query?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice; if you don't get answers you can [improve your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers).  I've closed your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26935368/266304) as a duplicate as this one now has answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query joins both tables and columns and displays which fields they have in common and if there is one missing, it shows it in the fourth column:

```
select orig.column_name
,      arch.column_name
,      case
       when orig.column_name is null
       then 'column doesn''t exist in orig'
       when arch.column_name is null
       then 'column doesn''t exist in arch'
       else 'exists in both'
       end
       status
from   ( select table_name
         ,      column_name
         from   all_tab_columns
         where  table_name = 'X'
       )
       orig
full
outer
join   ( select table_name
         ,      column_name
         from   all_tab_columns
         where  table_name = 'ARCH_X'
       )
       arch
on     orig.column_name = arch.column_name
```

Comment: How else to add 'and ORNER='RTM' in search conditions but rather a separate column?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: there are several owners of tables. It is necessary to conduct the test tables only one owner, adding to WHERE specific owner. e.g. OWNER='p_owner'.

Comment: Just add it to the `where`.

Comment: @MykhailoMarufenko: Yes, to both statements.

Comment: but how can this query find a difference in the column??? If column_name no in both tables (orig, arch), the result it misses because JOIN not happen.

Comment: I need to check to see whether all the columns from the ORIG.table are present in the ARCH.table...

Comment: You can see that in the results, right? What is wrong with the output?

Comment: all right in result. but i think, if some column_name present only in ORIG.table => the result doesn't indicates that this field is not present in ARCH.table.

Comment: It does. Give it a try.

Comment: because ACRH and ORIG table can't JOIN

Comment: That's why it is a `full outer join`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be in that part of query:

```
 SELECT TABLE_NAME  
  FROM all_tables core_t
  where TABLE_NAME not like 'ARCH_%' AND
  EXISTS (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM all_tables hist_t
    WHERE hist_t.TABLE_NAME  = concat('ARCH_', core_t.TABLE_NAME)

  )
```

You are trying to fetch records that match 2 condidtion in the same time: 
1) TABLE_NAME not like 'ARCH_%'
2) TABLE_NAME = concat ('ARCH_',TABLE_NAME)

Those are two conditions that stays in opposite sides.

Also you could fix prefixes for column names (TABLE_NAME can be from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS table or ALL_TABLES).